# php Detect if html5 play button pressed

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, html5-audio

In PHP can I detect if the play button is pressed when the html5 audio player opens from a hyperlink

```
        $line = "<a href=\"$namehref\"><font color='blue'>$name</font></a>";
        echo $line;
```

[image: Detect play button pressed]

Comment: No, PHP can not interact with UI elements. Attach Ajax action to that button and send info to back-end

Comment: PHP only runs on the server, it cannot directly detect browser events - while the user is interacting with your PHP, there isn't even any PHP script running. Use JavaScript to detect the play event, and then you can use an AJAX request to send info to the server about it, if that's necessary.

Comment: _"when the html5 audio player opens from a hyperlink"_ - if you _just_ link to your audio file, then you will probably not be able to react to any events on the resulting player at all - that player is not embedded into the context of your page. You will need to start by rewriting this so that an actual `audio` element that lives in the context of your page is what is playing the sound, then you will be able to attach a play event handler to that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language that does not have access to client-side events such as clicking on an HTML5 play button.

Comment: trying another way, but  cannot get the line to display the second variable, what would be the syntax  echo $line = "<a href=\"$click?$namehref\"><font color='red'>$name</font> 
                </a>";